# SSL Error at Composer Install

Tags: ssl, xampp, composer-php

While installing Composer to XAMPP, I got some errors. My system OS was Windows 7, how can I solve this and install Composer?

> Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
>   file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar.sig): failed to open stream: operation failed
>   Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
>   file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar.sig): failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: Here is what fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377300/470749

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install composer due to certificate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164321/cant-install-composer-due-to-certificate-issues)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you configured the path to the ca certificates in `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo=/full/path/to/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
openssl.cafile=/full/path/to/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

In case you don't have a ca certificate bundle download it:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt

To install Composer (without using cURL):

`php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

Or, to install Composer (with cURL):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

(If that doesn't work out, simple download the Composer PHAR via your browser.

https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

But, you will run into the issue again, when fetching packages, until you fix the certificate issue.)

Comment: I have download "ca-bundle.crt" file "C:\xampp\php" this after that i add two line php.ini file,curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\php\ca-bundle.crt",after i tried to install same error will come can u please help me

Comment: @ranjith probably you need to restart your apache service

Comment: Here is an easy way to fix the certificate problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377300/470749

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the same issue I'm facing. While installing the Composer Installer on my Windows 7 machine I'm getting the below error:

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Tried this:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
stdin is not a tty
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

And this:

```
$ ping getcomposer.org

Pinging getcomposer.org [87.98.253.108] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 87.98.253.108: bytes=32 time=137ms TTL=47
Reply from 87.98.253.108: bytes=32 time=127ms TTL=47
Reply from 87.98.253.108: bytes=32 time=127ms TTL=47
Reply from 87.98.253.108: bytes=32 time=127ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 87.98.253.108:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 127ms, Maximum = 137ms, Average = 129ms
```

My PHP version is:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.37 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2016 16:14:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

I've enabled the following list in my php.ini:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
curl.cainfo="C:/xampp/php/extras/certs/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:/xampp/php/extras/certs/cacert.pem"
```

Where I've downloaded the cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I was missing to add the proxy settings while installation, when added it worked like charm! :)

```
http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while changing php version on my Windows. Hope this could help someone.
php.ini didn't have right extensions and I just had to uncomment:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini of your php for me Im using ampps on mac and just changed it to:
curl.cainfo =/Applications/AMPPS/ca-bundle.crt
openssl.cafile =/Applications/AMPPS/ca-bundle.crt

After Updating php.ini, you need to restart your apache

You may download the ca-bundle.cer here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt and rename as ca-bundle.crt.

check attached for your reference before and after updating php.ini
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replace all "https" on "http" in install commands and in  "composer-setup.php" file.

```
vim composer-setup.php
:%s/https/http
```