# Can't install composer due to certificate issues

Tags: php, windows, laravel, ssl, composer-php

So I have tried all morning to install composer so I can start to use the laravel framework.

I am running windows server r2 standard 64bit with XAMPP on php 7.0

When running the Composer-Setup.exe I get the following message..

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation
>   failed

I have scoured the net, and in most cases, the issue that I seem to be having is specifying a cacert.pem file..

So I followed instructions to download the cert from - https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I simply made a .txt file, copied the content into it from the above link and renamed the file so it was cacert.pem file.

Then specified the .pem file inside the php.ini

> openssl.cafile=C:\cacert.pem

Restard apache then re ran the setup.

After running it again, I get exactly the same error about ssl operation failed with code 1.

Hopefully someone can see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: check this video for composer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQFZSfWI3-k    recently i used it

Comment: this video is related to cakePHP but at the starting part they guide how to install composer and get composer.phar file

Comment: I have already tried this.

Comment: on Git; Ticket with same problem https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798

Comment: could you disable ssl in your composer downloading? (not recommended)

Comment: can you check that the very same php.ini is used in the command line? To make sure invoke php like php --ini c:\xampp\[....]php.ini composer.phar (not composer.exe)

Comment: are your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you running the latest version of Composer?
2. Try to turn off HTTP proxy (if you have one).
3. Read [a ticket with the same problem](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798) to get more inspiration, if 1 & 2 did not help.

Comment: Yes, running latest version, 2. We don't have a proxy. and 3. tried everything I can find and still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to uncomment this line in your php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

After none of the answers I found online worked for me, even downloading a fresh certificate bundle and updating my php.ini, what worked was to pass the certificate bundle as a command line option to the installer:

```
php composer-setup.php --cafile /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you are behind firewall with

In Windows you must find composer temp folder(User temp folder) setup and rename redirect  https to http in file Composer-Setup.tmp

Answer (score -1):

is open_ssl enabled in php?

you may need to install open ssl using

apt-get install open-ssl

Comment: His question is about Windows Server