# PHP - file_get_contents() 'SSL: The operation completed successfully.' and 'Failed to enable crypto' at the same time (Google ReCaptcha)

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-5.6, recaptcha

A co-worker's come to me asking for some help figuring this particular error out. We're using google's recaptcha API for our registration and login forms, which does appear to be working as users have been accessing and registering on the software. However, our error log file is showing errors like this, appearing sporadically (I've stripped out certain things because this is from a production environment):

> [10-Jan-2017 18:37:21] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in file\path\save_register.php on line 76
>
> [10-Jan-2017 18:37:21] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in file\path\save_register.php on line 76
>
> [10-Jan-2017 18:37:21] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XYZ&response=): failed to open stream: operation failed in file\path\save_register.php on line 76
>
> [10-Jan-2017 18:37:21] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in file\path\save_register.php on line 76

Here's the relevant section of PHP code with their line numbers:

```
74: if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
75:   $recaptcha_secret = "XYZ";
76:   $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
77:   $response = json_decode($response, true);
78: }else {
79:   $response['success'] = false;
80: }
```

As a note, we've been unable to replicate this so far on our test environment which is (supposedly) the 'exact same' as production. Based on the error log, I can see that $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] is a null value. However, I'm currently uncertain if that would be the cause of the 'Failed to enable crypto' error that appeared before the failed to open stream error. I'm also uncertain as to why there would be a warning in the error log saying 'The operation completed successfully'.

The server is running PHP 5.6 on a Windows IIS server.

Comment: I saw another post tagged in [curl] earlier about a Windows person with the same issue (failed to enable crypto).  Might be a Windows/OpenSSL/network thing going on.  `Failed to enable crypto` is a PHP specific error related to the network transport itself.  Found that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164321/cant-install-composer-due-to-certificate-issues), seems to be unrelated.  A network issue could explain this error.  Instead of simple file_get_contents, you might try curl, at least would be interesting to see what happens or if anything changes.