# Can't install Composer, error in install already try several solutions

Tags: composer-php, installation

When the installation of Composer program starts this error occurs:

> The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].
>
> OpenSSL failed with a 'certificate verify failed' error. This
>   indicates a problem with the Certificate Authority file(s) on your
>   system, which either cannot be found or may be out of date.
>
> Script Output: The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not
>   be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:1416F086:SSL
>   routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed

I've already looked for some solutions on the internet, like deleting the; in the php.ini file but no solution so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install composer due to certificate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164321/cant-install-composer-due-to-certificate-issues)

Comment: Darn it. I can't find the proper issue, but this is a common problem on Windows. In your php.ini you have to specify the correct location where your certificates are stored. See for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php and https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798#issuecomment-68200214

Answer (score 0):

On Windows - Behind a corporate firewall/Proxies e.t.c

Using the official installation instructions for Composer.

```
php -r "copy('http://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

Use http://getcomposer.org/installer and not https://getcomposer.org/installer to avoid SSL Validation

```
// Removed the validation line -> php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

Modify the `php composer-setup.php` and add `--disable-tls` to disable ssl validation. Execute it as `php composer-setup.php --disable-tls`  . You can also modify the file directly replace `$uriScheme = $this->disableTls ? 'http' : 'https';` with `$uriScheme = 'http';`

Then continue with other installation steps.

```
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your system's Certificate Authority file(s):

- On Windows: You can download and run the latest Mozilla CA bundle
  from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and then set the path to
  this file in your php.ini file:
  openssl.cafile="C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
- On Linux/MacOS: You can run
  sudo update-ca-certificates to update the system's CA bundle.

2. Disable SSL verification (not recommended):

- Add the following line to your php.ini file: openssl.verify_peer=0

3. Install Composer using the --no-verify flag to skip SSL verification:

- Download the installer script using: php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
- Run the installer script using: php composer-setup.php --no-verify
- After installation, you can remove the --no-verify flag when running Composer commands.

It's recommended to try solution 1 first, as it's the most secure and reliable option.