# Composer install failed

Tags: php, curl, composer-php, failed-installation

I'm trying to install composer in my `Ubuntu 16.04` with `PHP version 5.6.*`.

I used:`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`. But it is giving me error as follows:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

I do not have composer installed previously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install composer due to certificate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164321/cant-install-composer-due-to-certificate-issues)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the issue by downloading  https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and giving it's path in my `etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini` and `etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`.

Then after running  `sudo service apache2 restart && sudo apt install composer` just worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal and run `php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());"`

Note the location of `default_cert_file`. It might say `\usr\local\ssl\cert.pem`
Verify that that file exists. If not, download the cacert.pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and place it in somewhere preferably in `/usr/local/ssl`

You now have a file is `usr/local/ssl/cacert.pem`

Open your php.ini and add the location of the file `openssl.cafile=cacert.pem`

Install composer

Run `composer config --global cafile "/usr/local/ssl/cacert.pem"`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a misconfiguration of PHP/openssl on your host.

My workstation is Ubuntu 16.04.3, php 7.0.22 and openssl-1.0.2g - the installer worked fine.

Try with TLS disabled:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls
```

Comment: "Fixing" this by disabling TLS is definitely not in the spirit of the poster's question...

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this problem while using Laravel Homestead after I’d accidentally emptied the contents of this file: `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

**What fixed it for me was:**

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates 
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351370/470749

Comment: thank you, it solved for me.
Before running "sudo apt-get install ca-certificates"
Run "sudo apt-get update"

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by my kaspersky internet security
I fixed it by disabling KIS temporary

you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Export proxy from https to http

Open Terminal

```
    echo $https_proxy
// Change export proxy from 
    https_proxy=https://192.168.0.10:8080/
// to 
   https_proxy=http://192.168.0.10:8080/
```

cmd:: `https_proxy=http://192.168.0.10:8080/`