# Error when trying to install composer on Windows 10

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, bitnami

I'm trying to install composer on Windows but I get the following error:

The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:

> error: 1416F086: SSL routines: tls_process_server_certificate:
>   certificate verify failed Failed to enable crypto failed to open
>   stream: operation failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer install failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241939/composer-install-failed)

Answer (score 1):

Use Command and check certificate is exists or not:

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

You will get Output like this :

> Array (
>
> [default_cert_file] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
>       [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
>       [default_cert_dir] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/certs
>       [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
>       [default_private_dir] =>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/private
>       [default_default_cert_area] =>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl
>       [ini_cafile] => 
>       [ini_capath] =>  )

Check :

> cert.pem file exists or not.

Comment: this command won't work because I am using Bitnami on windows 10 Environment. so if i try to run the php command i get the following error :'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: have you check php is installed or not in it?

Comment: @SachinAghera you forgot to share the ways to solve the problem. Just checking for the certificate store does not solve anything

Comment: @NicoHaase Most issue related to certificate

Comment: Yes, that's obvious from the question. But the main goal of SO is not to properly identify an issue, but to provide steps to solve it

Comment: @SachinAghera , yes php is installed

Comment: Then it should be run

Comment: Hi Bitnami Engineer here. In order to run the PHP commands you need to load the Bitnami Console (Start menu under "Start -> Bitnami APPNAME Stack -> Application console" or "Use APPNAME Stack" https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/bnconsole/#windows) if you installed a Bitnami Stack or run the php binary (specifying the whole path) if you are using XAMPP. If you need more help, could you please let us know the solution you used and the version of PHP it has? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For me disabling the Antivirus solved the issue

- Disable Antivirus
- Close the terminal
- Reopen the Terminal and type "composer diagnose" to check if problem is solved.
- Re-enable Antivirus

Comment: Please *never recommends to disable security features* as Antivirus. When it's needed, please specify one step to re-enable. Disabling of AV/Firewall is onle useful to detect source of problems, but not for solve problem.

Comment: @JakubBoucek sure, you have to re-enable antivirus later on