# PHP Composer HTTPS error 1416F086. Certificate verifying failed

Tags: php, https, composer-php

I suddenly get this nasty HTTPS error with PHP Composer and Composer used to work on my machine. There are already topics with the same issue on Github and also stackoverflow. I tried everything what is recommended but nothing works for me. I downloaded a new certificate and put it into `/usr/lib/ssl/certs`

- updated php
- updated composer
- There is no problem with `curl` to curl a https page.

`php modules` :

```
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

my system:

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Release:    18.2
Codename:   sonya
```

`print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());` output:

```
Array ( [default_cert_file] => /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE [default_cert_dir] => /usr/lib/ssl/certs [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR [default_private_dir] => /usr/lib/ssl/private [default_default_cert_area] => /usr/lib/ssl [ini_cafile] => /opt/atom/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/ssl/cacert.pem [ini_capath] => )
```

`composer install` error message:

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
   The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
   Failed to enable crypto
   failed to open stream: operation failed
```

my simple composer.json file

```
{
  "name": "root/helloworld",
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "~2",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "^3.0"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "23232323"
    }
  ]
}
```

Composer output terminal `composer diagnose`:

```
   composer diagnose
    Checking platform settings: OK
    Checking git settings: OK
    Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
    Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
    error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
    Failed to enable crypto
    failed to open stream: operation failed
    Checking github.com rate limit: OK
    Checking disk free space: OK
    Checking pubkeys: 
    Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
    Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
    OK
    Checking composer version: OK
    Composer version: 1.7.3
    PHP version: 7.2.12
    PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6529

Comment: Hey @НиколайЛубышев i have no issues with sudo apt-get install.

Comment: Hmm. `composer diag error - SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages` title of issue with my link. If this is not what you are asked - sorry )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates 

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

`composer diagnose`

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.7.3
PHP version: 7.2.12
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.2
```