# Having problem with install composer in xampp 3.2.2 and php 7.2.10

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I have **Xampp 3.2.2** and **php 7.2.10** in **windows 10** when I want to install the latest version of **composer** I have an error :
[The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].

Script Output:

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

[image: Error output]

what should I do for solve this problem?
Thanks for your guidance...

Comment: Please follow the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197412/ssl-error-at-composer-install

Comment: I checked that link before but my problem was different, now it solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved...

I installed composer with command-line, and then run the .exe file without proxy server, then it worked.